# Tikz-cd in Latex in Inkscape, arrow lines disappear

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, tikz-cd, inkscape

I am using a "render Latex" function in Inkscape.

In the input box I use this code:

```
\begin{tikzcd} A \arrow{r} {x} & C \\ B \arrow{r} {x} \arrow[u, "F"] & D \arrow[u, "F"]\end{tikzcd}
```

For some mysterious reason, the arrow lines disappeared in the rendered result:

[image: result1]

If I add the option `math font` with the following code:

```
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}  \begin{tikzcd} A \arrow{r} {x} & C \\ B \arrow{r} {x} \arrow[u, "F"] & D \arrow[u, "F"]\end{tikzcd}
```

The result becomes like this:

[image: result2]

Without looking into the Latex plug-in for Inkscape, 
can we guess at what is the problem and how to fix it?

PS:
If I set `arrow style=tikz` arrow lines disappear. 
If I set `arrow style=Latin Modern` arrows lines also disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

That problem was with Inkscape 0.92 and an old plug-in, 
but with Inkscape 1.0 and another Latex plug-in the problem is gone.

I will leave the question here in case others have the same problem.